# How to assign a value to a variable in Terminal?

Tags: command-line

In Terminal, how can I set a new variable and assign a value to it? Let's say I want to compare two files with long file names and then  also perform some other operations. Because of the long file names I'd like to create two variables, assign value to each variable and use it as place-holder. I need something like the following:

```
set var1 = 'long-file-name1'
set var2 = 'long-file-name2'
diff var1 var2
```

Comment: Which *shell* you are using in your terminal? `set` is only used for assignment in shells of the `csh` family - for Bourne type shells (including POSIX `sh` and `bash`) the syntax is simply `var1='long-file-name1'`. See for example [Bash: why isn't “set” behaving like I expect it to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9255/bash-why-isnt-set-behaving-like-i-expect-it-to)

Comment: @steeldriver: I'm using the one that came with Ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the file name in a variable in bash simply by assigning it

For example:`variable=filename && variable2=filename2`

you can then `diff` the two files using those variables like this
`diff $variable $variable2`

NB:if your filenames have spaces it is best to double quote both the filenames and the variables especially when performing operations with them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101329/discussion-between-fuseteam-and-blueskies).

Answer (score 12):

The pseudocode (or code for some other shell or programming language) in your question translates to the following Bash commands:

```bash
var1='long-file-name1'
var2='long-file-name2'
diff "$var1" "$var2"
```

The syntax `$var1` is [**parameter expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). This replaces the variable `var1` with its value--in this case, with the filename stored in it. Unquoted parameter expansion triggers [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) (also called "field splitting") and [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) (also called "filename expansion" and "pathname expansion"). Usually you don't want those further expansions to occur. [Except when you specifically know you want them](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), you should [make sure to enclose](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) all occurrences of parameter expansion in [**double quotes**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes). ([Single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) are even more powerful--they would prevent parameter expansion from happening, too.)

That runs the `diff` command with the filename stored in `var1` passed as its first command-line argument and the filename stored in `var2` passed as its second command-line argument. [This causes `diff` to compare the contents of the files](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/diff.1.html), as you intend, just as it would if you had run:

```bash
diff 'long-file-name-1' 'long-file-name-2'
```

**You will notice that I have not used the `export` command.** That's because, in this case, the `export` command is [neither necessary nor appropriate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107851/using-export-in-bashrc) for what you are doing. When the value of a variable only needs to be expanded in your shell--and not [accessed by programs started from your shell](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)--then you do not need to (and should not) use `export`.

If your system had a strange `diff` command that read filenames from environment variables called `var1` and `var2` rather than taking filenames as command-line arguments, then you would need to export your variables. But that's not how `diff` works. The `diff` command is not accessing--and does not know anything about--your variables. The shell is expanding them to produce the arguments it then passes to `diff`.